# How to secure acces to user uploaded files with a filter in Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am building a Grails application which uses the [Spring Security Core Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core).

I have two applications roles. ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN

Users can upload files which are stored in a directory called *files*

1. External users should not see any file
2. ROLE_ADMIN users can see every uploaded file.
3. ROLE_USER user should be allowed only in certain cases

A file url request should look like this

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/files/patient1-1.png
```

For the first case I have set in conf/Config.groovy the next url interceptor

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/files/**': ['ROLE_USER']
]
```

For the second and third case I created the next file conf/MyFilters

```
class MyFilters {
    def springSecurityService

    public currentUser() {  return User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id);}
    public userRoles()   { return springSecurityService.principal.authorities*.authority }

    def filters = {
        fileFilter(uri: '/files/*') {
            before = {
                println "Here"
                def String url = request.getRequestURL()
                if(url.contains("files/patient")) {
                    if(!userRoles().contains(Role.ROLE_ADMIN)) {
                        if(PLAIN ROLE USER IS NOT ALLOWED) {
                          redirect(action:'login')
                          return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            after = {

            }
            afterView = {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, it does not seem to get triggered. I never see the *Here* print out.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to use /files/** in your filter url matching rule? what happens when your activate the filter for all urls, can you see your print msg?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mix Grails filters with Spring Security - everything is doable from Spring Security. Are you using the "InterceptUrlMap" config type (`grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"`)? By default it uses annotations, so the `securityConfigType` setting would be ignored.

If you're using annotations you can add this url pattern to the `staticRules` config option:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
   '/files/**': ['ROLE_USER']
]
```

Try running `grails clean` to force a full compile; it might be a simple as some code being out of sync.